# Script to replace certain cells in a row on a specified date?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use Google Sheets to maintain client contact records.

**Is there a script to replace certain cells in a row on a specified date?**

Specifically, I want a contact's address to automatically update the day they move into a new home.

Address 1: 123 Main Street

Address 2: 999 Smith Drive

Moving Date:  July 1, 2020

On July 1st Address 1 needs to be deleted and replaced with Address 2.

I have some knowledge of apps script but perhaps you can tell by my question that it is very limited lol.
Any help or advice you can provide is much appreciated!

Here is a [Sample Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1azZTTsLf7aCtIFlJt30oULaZy9bMQ1Fl1CiyKR_1eGU/edit?usp=sharing) of the columns.

Comment: Welcome.  [Time-driven Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) allow you to specify that a trigger can be run on a specific date/time. However, your situation is challenging because you can't associate a trigger with a specific record. Rather you may find that it is better to run a script once a day, the script scans the "Moving date" Column, and only exuctes for those dates that are equal to "today's date".

Comment: @Tedinoz That makes perfect sense, thank you for this suggestion.  Are you familiar with a script I could augment to switch the addresses out?